# C++ Pointer to Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```c
    short* m_pDataBuf; //global variable
    void foo(){
        m_pDataBuf = new short[100];
    }

    void bar(){
        short* srcData = &m_pDataBuf[0];
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            srcData[i]= i*5; 
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        foo();
        bar();
        short* srcData = &m_pDataBuf[0];
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            cout<<srcData[i]<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

In `bar()` I think the `m_pDataBuf` will be filled with 100 elements but totally `m_pDataBuf` is an array with one element (just 100th element);

What is wrong?

Comment: I compile this code on VS2017

Comment: What is exactly your output? On g++ I'm getting sequence of 100 numbers, from 5 to 495, just as expected

Comment: Not related. You have memory leak. Every new comes with a delete

Comment: m_pDataBuf is not an array. It is a pointer. Pointers are not arrays. m_pDataBuf points to the first element of a 100-wlement array. None of this is important, you should almost never be using C-style pointers or arrays anyway.

Comment: *"totally m_pDataBuf is an array with one element (just 100th element)"* - The array `m_pDataBuf` points to has 100 elements as you created it `new short[100]`.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m This is a project that written in VC++ 6.0 and now I have to update it. What is your opinion?

Comment: @RashidBagheriRash what you want to update if it is working? Just add array deletion at the end to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @RashidBagheri how did you come to the conclusion that you have only one element and it's the 100th element?

Comment: What is the problem with updating it? Do you have compilation errors? Run-time errors?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' Project written in VC++ 6.0 and now I want to compile from VS2017. Now, the project runs without error but all arrays like m_pDataBuffer has wrong size.

Comment: @arsdever I'm new in c++. Could you help me about memory leaks?

Comment: @RashidBagheri How can I help you? Probably, you should read about them, understand what they are and how to handle them. In this particular case, you must add the following before returning from the main function `delete[] m_pDataBuf`. But to deeply understand the purpose of the statement, please have a look at memory leak related topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use raw pointers. Don't use new and delete. Use STL containers.

Don't use global variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

void bar(vector<short> &data){
    data.resize(100);
    for(short i {0}; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        data[i] = i*5; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<short> data;
    bar(data);
    for(const auto &el : data){
        cout << el << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why force to use STL? Maybe suggest to use Qt containers, or boost containers?

Comment: @arsdever STL is part of the C++ standard. They are delivered with the compiler. No need to download, install and link other libraries

Comment: @arsdever Qt containers come with license restrictions and why would you choose to use third party libraries when you can use the standard ones?

Comment: Good advice but this doesn't really answer the question. Probably better as a comment.

Comment: @Galik OP asks in the comments for help with memory leaks. The simplest solution to avoid memory leaks is the usage of containers. This answer shows a possible way to achieve the same functionality without memory leaks.